# Passing two argument variables in grep while ignoring whitespace

Tags: shell, grep

I'm trying to write a shell script that takes a parameter to search column 12 of a given csv file for a matching pattern, and then search for a pattern match in column 18 as another argument, both of which being strings that may or may not include a space. However what I've tried so far only takes the second argument up until whitespace, then begins thinking it is a nonexistent command. My code appears as such:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -Po "^([^,]*,){11}$2*([^,]*){9}" "$1" | grep -E "^([^,]*,){17}$3*([^,]*){4}"
```

Wherein $2 is the pattern to be searched in column 12, $1 is the name of csv file, and $3 is the pattern to be searched in column 18. This also does not print any of the columns following column 12, when I would like to print the entire line (about 21-22 columns total). What am I doing incorrectly? (For context, fields are separated by commas in the test file being used). Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're working with CSV files, I strongly suggest looking at awk which handles them much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor error in your first regex:

```bash
"^([^,]*,){11}$2*([^,]*){9}" # your regex
"^([^,]*,){11}$2*(,[^,]*){9}" # correct regex
```

And there's a similar error in the 2nd regex.

I suggest you merge the regexes to make one command:

```
grep -Po "^([^,]*,){11}$2*(,[^,]*){5},$3(,[^,]*){4}" "$1"
```

The `-o` flag only prints the *matching* part, so you won't get any more output than what's matched by the first regex. Consider removing `-o` flag if you just want the whole line.